# Return value of html dialog to be used in script

Tags: google-apps-script, modal-dialog

I have a dropdown populated with sheet names in an HTML dialog box.

I need to return the value chosen in the dropdown and use it in a later script.

How do I return the value chosen from the HTML dialog so I can use it in a new function?

function something(returned-Value) {
stuff
}

gas

```
function getDialog() {

 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
     .setWidth(400)
     .setHeight(300);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'New Component Form');
 }


function getList() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getName()!=="FullOptionLists" && sheets[i].getName()!=="sumAppHeaders" && sheets[i].getName()!=="RawData") {
       out.push(sheets[i].getName())
    }
  }

  return out; 
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
  <body onload="addList()">
    <form id="Form">
      <div>
        <label for="List">Select Value:</label><br>
        <input list="dropdownList" name="list" placeholder="Choose Value" required>
          <datalist id="dropdownList">
          </datalist>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

  <script>
    function addList() {
      google.script.run
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(addListValues)
        .getList();
    }

    function addListValues(values) {
      var list = document.getElementById('dropdownList');   
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option"); // Modified
        option.value = values[i]; // Modified
        list.appendChild(option); // Modified
      }
    }

    function onFailure(err) {
      alert('There was an error!' + err.message);
    }
  </script>

<HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return Value from HTML dialog:

gs:

```
function launchAQuickDialog() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah2");
  ui.showModelessDialog(html,"Get Data");
}

function saveMyNewData(v) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("Name",v);
  Logger.log(getMyNewData())
} 

function getMyNewData() {
  let data = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("Name");
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(`Data:${data}`)
  return data;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="text" id="txt1" onChange="google.script.run.saveMyNewData(this.value)">
   <select id="sel1" onChange="google.script.run.saveMyNewData(this.value);">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Properties Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties)

Demo:

[image]

You can do a similar thing by using the id's as keys into the Properties Service

GS:

```
function saveMyNewData(obj) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(obj.key,obj.value);
  Logger.log(getMyNewData(obj))
} 

function getMyNewData(obj) {
  let data = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(obj.key);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(`Data:${data}`)
  return data;
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="text"  id="txt1" onChange="google.script.run.saveMyNewData({key:this.id,value:this.value})">
   <select id="sel1" onChange="google.script.run.saveMyNewData({key:this.id,value:this.value});">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
  </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

With this method you now how the values stored separately.  You can go up into project settings and see the ScriptProperties.

Comment: Yes, this looks like it will get me there. I will try and add dynamic sheet names to this. Thank you

Comment: The perfect tutorial on how to do this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETrv-lw6Rv4